# How to format decimal places in Aspose.Word Template?

Tags: aspose.words

I want all numerical data to be formatted with 2 decimal places.
Is there a way to set this in the template word file (where I output the variable value via
**<<[variableName] >>**
), or even globally?

Answer (score 1):

To format a numeric expression result, you can specify a format string as an element of the corresponding expression tag.

```
<<[variableName]:"0.##">>
```

See the following article for more information:
https://docs.aspose.com/words/net/outputting-expression-results/